# How do I run specs for the activeadmin gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I am trying to run the specs for a local clone of the [activeadmin gem](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin)s current master.

I am using ruby 2.2.2 and have bundled successfully.
When I try to run one of the specs like so:

```
bundle exec rspec spec/unit/filters/humanized_spec.rb
```

I am getting the following error:

`` The git source https://github.com/jruby/activerecord-jdbc-adapter is not yet checked out. Please run `bundle install` before trying to start your application
Coverage report generated for RSpec to /Users/aljoscha/gem/activeadmin/coverage. 0.0 / 0.0 LOC (100.0%) covered.
/Users/aljoscha/gem/activeadmin/spec/rails_helper.rb:13:in `require': cannot load such file -- active_record (LoadError)
    from /Users/aljoscha/gem/activeadmin/spec/rails_helper.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/aljoscha/gem/activeadmin/spec/unit/filters/humanized_spec.rb:1:in `require'
    from /Users/aljoscha/gem/activeadmin/spec/unit/filters/humanized_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/aljoscha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1435:in `load'
    from /Users/aljoscha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1435:in `block in load_spec_files'
    from /Users/aljoscha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1433:in `each'
    from /Users/aljoscha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1433:in `load_spec_files'
    from /Users/aljoscha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:100:in `setup'
    from /Users/aljoscha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:86:in `run'
    from /Users/aljoscha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:71:in `run'
    from /Users/aljoscha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:45:in `invoke'
    from /Users/aljoscha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rspec-core-3.5.4/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/aljoscha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/bin/rspec:22:in `load'
    from /Users/aljoscha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/bin/rspec:22:in `<main>'
    from /Users/aljoscha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /Users/aljoscha/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>' ``

which I cannot make sense of.

Especially since `activerecord-jdbc-adapter` is not even in the Gemfile.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try prepending your command with `bundle exec`:

```
bundle exec rspec spec/unit/filters/humanized_spec.rb
```

It looks like you have a local version discrepancy causing issues.

If not, did you follow all of the steps listed on their [contributing readme](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#3-get-the-test-suite-running)?

---

If you are still stuck, you may be experiencing an issue with `bundler` itself.  First, try updating `bundler` then reinstalling gems and attempt to run rspec.  If that doesn't work you may need to delete the bundle cache folder and start over.

Comment: Thanks, I was completely unaware of the contributing readme. Executing `bundle exec appraisal install` solved the missing dependency.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to re-answer to emphasize how to test a gem using [appraisal](https://github.com/thoughtbot/appraisal) as mentioned in [CONTIBUTING](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#3-get-the-test-suite-running):

```
bundle exec appraisal install
bundle exec appraisal rails_50 rspec spec/unit/filters/humanized_spec.rb
```

Thank you for your interest in Active Admin.